# How to neatly write two functions - one for checking if a solution exists, and another one for getting all solutions?

Tags: c++

The obvious way is to just write two functions, but then they are almost identical. What I'm doing now is a function template with the return type (either `bool` or `vector<something>`) as the argument

```
template<typename ReturnType>
ReturnType foo(...){
    constexpr bool return_bool = std::is_same<ReturnType, bool>::value;
    ResultType results; //hopefully, the compiler takes it out in the bool case
```

And the plan is to use `if constexpr(return_bool)` when needed. But then I get this reoccurring piece of code

```
ReturnType result = foo<ResultType>(...);
if constexpr(return_bool){
    if(result) return true;
}else std::copy(result.begin(), result.end(), std::back_inserter(results));
```

The return statement makes it hard to use standard anti-repetition techniques. I could use macros but then perhaps the repetition is better. Getting either all solutions or just the information whether one exists seems like a fairly general problem, is there a better way to do it?

I should've added that the function is performance-critical in the "does a solution exist?" case. That's why I want to have another version there and also why I don't want any costly abstractions.

Comment: What about std::optional as return type?

Comment: An empty vector could signal that no solutions were found.

Comment: @cigien see edit

Comment: @Equod see edit, if the question remains unanswered then please elaborate.

Comment: Ok, I see what you mean. I would suggest returning early as soon as any solution is found, which avoids the performance loss. Then a non-empty vector being returned would still convey the same information.

Comment: @cigien You mean always extending the vector and only repeating `if constexpr(return_bool) if(!results.empty()) return results;`? That's neater, however, I tried it right now and it doubled time (`clang++-10 -O3`)

Comment: No, I mean `return results` as soon as a solution is found. This depends on your particular algorithm, so you should show that.

Comment: @cigien perhaps I didn't emphasize it but it's a recursive function (in fact a backtrack). So "as soon as a solution is found" is somewhere deep in the call stack. Does that specify the algorithm enough? I'm reluctant to show since it's a bit ugly.

I fear that passing any answer at all instead of a bool will bear a performance cost.

Comment: There is a probably a solution for what you want, but you'll have to show a working example. Try and simplify it as much as possible, so it only shows the relevant material.

Answer (score 0):

You want two opposite features :

1. Reusing one solution in the other to avoid replication
2. Having an optimized version for *solutionExists()* to avoid a full result search

You didn't specify what is the solution your function returns, so I will explain why you can't have both using a simple example : your function is returning the number of ocurences of 0 in a vector of integers.

The function returning all solutions would look like this :

```
int GetNumberOfOccurencesOf0(const vector<int>& data)
{
  int occurences = 0;
  for (int i : data)
  {
    if (i == 0)
      ++occurences;
  }
  return occurences;
}
```

If you are not concerned about performance, your function for returning if there is a solution can be :

```
bool AreThereOccurencesOf0(const vector<int>& data)
{
  return (GetNumberOfOccurencesOf0(data) > 0);
}
```

Note that there is no code duplication but the solution is not optimal : the data vector is iterated entirely. If you want an optimized solution, it would look like this :

```
bool AreThereOccurencesOf0(const vector<int>& data)
{
  for (int i : data)
  {
    if (i == 0)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

If your problem requires an optimized version of *solutionExists()*, you should write it and it should not need to reuse code from the *getAllSolutions()* function.

Comment: I don't see how these are opposite - if there are no two versions (2) then surely there can't be reusing one version inside the other (1). It can be done with macros, I'm just looking for a nicer way.

Comment: @acupoftea If you write optimized function yourself, there is no duplication to avoid, except maybe for the loop. But this code was just to show the algorithm, if a real case you would probably use algorithms from the std anyway.
If you don't need an optimized version, then the first version is your solution. 
Maybe you could explain the problem you are solving, I might not have understood your question

Comment: The example you gave is very simple so there really isn't that much avoidable repetition. Mine is a bit more involved. It's a backtrack with exponential solution space. Imagine if there was also a rule that the zeroes can't be after a `3` - then the code for skipping those zeroes would be repeated. With a few more rules like this and with more general complexity I quickly feel the need to make avoid repetition.